# @Formula in Hibernate to calculate Date time

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, formula

I need to calculate train arrival time based on depart time and duration through @Formula in hibernate entity. The depTime is Java util Date and duration in Minutes.I need to add deptime with duration through @Formula.To add minutes in datetime I thought to use DateUtils of Apache commons .But i am unable to complete the formula.
Help me how to achieve this .

```
@Column(name = "DEP_TIME")
private Date depTime;

@Column(name = "DURATION")
private int duration;

@Formula(DateUtils.addMinutes(depTime,duration))
private Date arrTime;
```

If I defined above Im getting compilation error in @Formula

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Date 
     to String.
```

Help If there any alternative ways to achieve this in Hibernate entity.

Thanks

Comment: You can convert datetime to millisecond...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `@Formula` tag only accepts a `String` value, which represents SQL. Your expression results in a `Date` value.

In the `@Formula` tag you should use an SQL expression instead of a Java expression.

Docs: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Formula.html